# Html dont open file in browser

Tags: html, file, web

Maybe its stupid question, but I don't know to find answer anywhere.

When I navigate to my file for example: mysite.com/folder/sometextfile.txt 
it automatically opens the file and shows content in browser.

What do I have to do if I don't want to show content in browser, but have options to open file or download it?

I have tried

```
  <form method="post" action="../folder/sometextfile.txt">
  <button type="submit">Download!</button>
  </form>
```

and

```
<a href= "../folder/sometextfile.txt">Textfile</a>
```

But it still shows the content of file.

I dont want to something special, just the default way which it is done in most cases.

Comment: The HTML has no control over this.  It's a combination of the headers sent from the server and how the browser is configured to handle that type of content.  If you can configure the server to send a `Content-Disposition` header with the file identifying it as a "file" (or "attachment" I think, with a file name and whatnot) then that suggests to the browser that it should be saved instead of displayed.  The browser can override this, of course, depending on its own configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on the server side settings, by default the web server knows some common file extensions like .txt, .html etc. It is called MIME Types. If you remove the txt extension form the server, all the txt files will be downloaded automatically. 
http://webdesign.about.com/od/multimedia/a/mime-types-by-file-extension.htm

Or you can simply zip it and upload :P

Comment: I have found tool that configures MIME types in my CPanel. All the freqently used types are defined in System MIME Types that can't be deleted. Do you know some way to delete some of theese types or define somewhere manually?